# Filter users with FIRST transaction higher than threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I got the following assignment for a test: Write a query to identify users whose first transaction was a successful card payment over $10 USD equivalent

What I've done is to make sure the transactions are applied to "USD equivalent" and making sure that the transaction amount is not expressed in the lowest unit such as pennies (through exponent).

I'm now struggling to filter my table for the first transaction of any user and having that to be above 10 USD equivalent (I tried to use a WHERE statement on "amount", but there wasn't any assigned variable to it (according to SQL Server).

```
SELECT t.USER_ID, 
SUM(t.amount / fx.rate / power(10, cd.exponent)) AS amount, 
t.CURRENCY, 
t.CREATED_DATE

FROM transactions$ t
JOIN fx_rates$ fx ON (fx.ccy = t.currency AND fx.base_ccy = 'USD')
JOIN currency_details$ cd ON cd.currency = t.currency

WHERE t.STATE = 'COMPLETED' 
AND t.TYPE = 'CARD_PAYMENT'

GROUP BY t.USER_ID, t.CURRENCY, t.CREATED_DATE
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

The query works, but I'd need direction into these two problems!

Comment: What does "works" mean? What does "there wasn't any assigned variable to it" mean? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) If you get messages or results you don't understand, put your overall goal on hold & debug re your misconceptions.

Comment: All the parts to this are faqs. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate the rows and then filter using that:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.USER_ID, 
             (t.amount / fx.rate / power(10, cd.exponent)) AS amount, 
             t.CURRENCY, 
             t.CREATED_DATE,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.USER_ID ORDER BY t.CREATED_DATE) as seqnum
      FROM transactions$ t JOIN
           fx_rates$ fx
           ON fx.ccy = t.currency AND fx.base_ccy = 'USD' JOIN
           currency_details$ cd
           ON cd.currency = t.currency
      WHERE t.STATE = 'COMPLETED' AND t.TYPE = 'CARD_PAYMENT'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND amount >= 10;
```